# Commands not working

Tags: warning-messages

[image: Error box when exiting a notebook.]

Today all commands have stopped working. When I try to exit a notebook it give the error box shown here. I reinstalled Mathematica and the commands still do not work.
I think I found the problem: It was trying to solve something it could no solve. I change Solve to NSolve and things then started working.

Comment: Really all commands? Even something like `1+1`? Have you changed your `Init.m` file at any time? That's a file that is processed after each kernel start. Maybe there is some expression hanging in there that does not get evaluated successfully. The file is usually stored in a folder in the user's home directory and thus does not change after reinstalling Mathematica. E.g. on macos it is located somewhere in  /Library/Mathematica (unfortunately, I don't know where it is of other operating systems). You might try to erase the whole folder, deinstall Mathematica and reinstall again.

Comment: Something else that just comes to my mind; I don't dare to ask: Have you already entered your license key?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.